# Changing view angle distorts sphere with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I am trying to learn how to use `pgfplots` by plotting simple things, like a two-dimensional sphere. However, I find it quite surprising that depending on the view angle, the result sometimes does not look like a sphere at all. Unless I am missing something, a sphere should like the same no matter which direction we are looking from.

Here is my example code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{width=6cm}

\newcommand{\degree}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
\newcommand{\plotsphere}[2]{
\begin{axis}[view={#2}{#1},axis equal,title={$\theta=#1\degree,\quad \phi=#2\degree$}]
\addplot3[surf,shader=flat,z buffer=sort,
samples=20,domain=-1:1,y domain=0:2*pi]
({sqrt(1-x^2) * cos(deg(y))},
{sqrt( 1-x^2 ) * sin(deg(y))},
x);
\end{axis}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.75]
\foreach \x/\polangle in {-8/20,0/45,8/70}
    \foreach \y / \azangle in {-8/20,0/45,8/70}
        \node at (\x,\y) {\plotsphere{\polangle}{\azangle}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

The only version I am satisfied with is `view={45}{45}`. All the other ones appear distorted. It seems that this distortion does not come from different length units on the axis because I am using the `axis equal` option. Am I forgetting some important parameter?

Comment: Actually they are distorted, look at the tick marks. Try `axis equal image`.

Comment: @zeroth please turn your comment into an answer, with a few screenshots to demonstrate :)

Comment: @cmhughes at the time of writing I did not know if it would help. I will apply some tests. Thanks!

Comment: Update the package. In the current version (1.6), this bug has been fixed.

Comment: @zeroth With the version of `pgfplots` (1.5.1) I had, using `axis equal image` didn't solve the problem, but upgrading to (1.6) as @Luigi suggested solves the problem, thank you very much (then I can use any axis scaling as illustrated in your answer).

Comment: @Corentin, yes. I only suspected that it was the reason (which it wasn't). However, when I had access to a TeX installation it was not a problem. My initial comment was a guess... :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Luigi correctly states, it was a bug which has been fixed in the 1.6 version.

Therefore an update will solve your problem. For the record try and see the difference between `axis equal` and `axis equal image` in the following figures.

#### No axis scaling

Of course here the scaling is wrong.

[image]

#### `axis equal` option

Here the scaling is *correct*. It will scale the axis limits so that it **keeps** the width and height that has been specified (that is `<axis>min` and `<axis>max` are subjected to the scaling). Hence you will see that it has tendencies to *fill* with a lot of white space if one does not have correct spacings (notice that in `\theta=45`).

[image]

#### `axis equal image` option

The scaling is also *correct* here. However, here the `<axis>min` and `<axis>max` are **not** the scaling parameters. Instead the width and height of the image is matched that of the found `<axis>min` and `<axis>max` lengths. Thus the image size will **not** be retained, even if specified.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this detailed post. I still don't get it though. I experience something like in the lower right examples with my own code, too. So how do I get the effect of `axis equal image` but with a fixed size of the picture produced?

Comment: @Christian in that case I would rely on the `axis equal` and then fit your own size. This does what you want, I suppose (I am not really clear what you have done etc.)

Comment: No, I don't want the white space that this gives me. I ended up adjusting the viewing angle so that the size more or less fits. I still have one rather high plot that doesn't fill the page width but I guess I can live with that. I still think this part of `pgfplots` could be more intuitive :/

Comment: Ah, I think I know what you meant now. Ok, yes, this is not trivially done. 3D in TeX is cumbersome... ;)