# Drawing sea shells using PGF/TikZ

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams

I'm trying to draw a sea shell using PGF/TikZ. The shape of the shell is based on a set of parametric equations plotted in 3D. (Source: [Math Parametric Equation for Seashell](http://xahlee.info/SpecialPlaneCurves_dir/Seashell_dir/seashell_math_formulas.html))

For those familiar with MATLAB, I've written some code which gives a working solution:

```matlab
R=1;    % Radius
N=3.6;  % Number of turns
H=2;    % Height
P=2;    % Power

samples = 100;
[x,y] = meshgrid(0:2*pi/(samples-1):2*pi);

X = (x/(2*pi*R)).*cos(N*x).*(1+cos(y));
Y = (x/(2*pi*R)).*sin(N*x).*(1+cos(y));
Z = (x/(2*pi*R)).*sin(y) + H*(x/(2*pi)).^P;

% PLOTTING
surf(X,Y,Z,X)
set(gca,'ZDir','reverse')
axis off
axis equal
shading interp
material dull 
lighting gouraud
lightangle(80,-40)
lightangle(-90,60)
```

[image]

This is what I've achieved so far in LaTeX, based off [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70337/128068) from [How to draw a Torus](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348/how-to-draw-a-torus):

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\N}{3.6}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\H}{2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\P}{2}
  \begin{axis}
     \addplot3[
         surf,
         colormap/cool,
         samples=60,
         domain=0:2*pi,
         y domain=0:2*pi,
         z buffer=sort]
        ({(x/(2*pi*\R))*cos(\N*deg(x))*(1+cos(deg(y)))},
         {(x/(2*pi*\R))*sin(\N*deg(x))*(1+cos(deg(y)))},
         {(x/(2*pi*\R))*sin(deg(y)) + \H*(x/(2*pi))^\P});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Can anyone help get this looking better? I've been trying to reverse the `z` axis, make the axes equal and remove the axes lines and labels. Additionally, I'm unsure of the capabilities of PGF/TikZ when it comes to things like shading and lighting. So would be interested to know what can be achieved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is only a little typo in the y component.  It should be `sin(\N*deg(x))` instead of `cos(\N*deg(x))`.  Then it looks fine, see this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyOEQ.png) with 100 samples.

Comment: To mimic the MATLAB figure you can also add `z dir=reverse`.

Comment: @HenriMenke How about just writing an answer (in which you in addition switch to a newer version, increase the sample and perhaps change the view)? Why is it off-topic?

Comment: @marmot Because it is just a typo.  I don't see how other users would benefit from me correcting a typo here.

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't spot this typo! Thanks. I will update my question. But I still have questions about shading/lighting

Comment: @HenriMenke I think it is an important typo, though. Without your correction people may think it is not possible to do this with pgfplots.

Comment: @Myles I see, I retracted my close vote and upvoted :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If Henri Menke post's his answer, I'll be happy to remove mine. I made a few adjustments, but the most crucial thing is the replacement Henri mentioned first. Other features (all minor compared to the impact of the typo) include:

- `shader=interp` to have a smooth surface
- adjusting the lighting angle via `point meta`
- `axis equal` and `unit vector ratio={}` to have the axes equal
- changed the viewing angle
- reversed the z direction simply by multiplying the z-component by -1
- removed the axis lines
- changed the color map
- increased the number of samples

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.16} %<- changed, 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\N}{3.6}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\H}{2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\P}{2}
  \begin{axis}[view={-40}{30},%<- added
         axis lines=none,%<- added : removes the axes
         axis equal,%<- added : makes the axes equal
         unit vector ratio={} %<- why did I add this? honestly, I don't know 100%        
         ] % I tried this because of the statement "An empty value unit vector ratio={} disables unit vector rescaling."
         % on page 299 of the pgfplots manual
     \addplot3[
         surf,shader=interp, %<- added : shading
         colormap/viridis, %<- changed : closer to the MatLAB picture (?)
         samples=60, %<- changed :
         domain=0:2*pi, 
         y domain=0:2*pi,
         point meta=z-y, %<- shading : fake a light impact angle
         z buffer=sort]
        ({(x/(2*pi*\R))*cos(\N*deg(x))*(1+cos(deg(y)))},
         {(x/(2*pi*\R))*sin(\N*deg(x))*(1+cos(deg(y)))},
         {-(x/(2*pi*\R))*sin(deg(y)) - \H*(x/(2*pi))^\P}); %<- minus added
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for fun: `point meta=z-sqrt(y^2+2*x^2)-1.5*y,`

[image]

But I think it is at least very hard (if not impossible) to achieve something of the quality of [J Leon V.'s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/431067/121799) with the current version of pgfplots. (Nevertheless, I am very impressed by that package, yet I'd agree with J Leon V. that asymptote is much better suited to draw such things.)

Comment: I've retracted my downvote and removed my comment.

Comment: @HenriMenke I think the comment was fair, but thanks nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks for this @marmot. The z-axis looks very squashed though? I've been reading this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74680/changing-view-angle-distorts-sphere-with-pgfplots

Comment: @Myles I (partly) "solved" the problem but I still must admit that I do not fully control the width of the plot.

Answer (score 9):

I know you ask for a solution in PGF or Tikz, and they are good but there are also more powerful tools for this type of graphics for example using Asymptote:

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode, shell: yes}
% arara: asymptote
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode, shell: yes}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
    \begin{asy}
        import graph3;
        import palette;
        size(200,0);
        currentprojection=perspective(
        camera=(1,-5.3,2),
        up=(0,0,1),
        target=(0,0,0),
        zoom=0.85);

        real R=1;
        real N=3.6;
        real H=2;
        real P=1.9;

        triple f(pair t) {
        return ((t.x/(2*pi*R))*cos(N*t.x)*(1+cos(t.y)),(t.x/(2*pi*R))*sin(N*t.x)*(1+cos(t.y)),(-t.x/(2*pi*R))*sin(t.y) - H*(t.x/(2*pi))^P);
        }

        surface s=surface(f,(0,0),(2pi,2pi),20,20,Spline);
        s.colors(palette(s.map(xpart),Gradient(green,blue)));

        draw(s,meshpen=black,render(merge=true));

    \end{asy}
\end{document}
```

I know tha is powerfull, if you want to compile with arara you can use the following YAML file. in [marmot's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/428592/154390), there he also explains how to compile it normally using shellscape.

You can see examples and download in the [asymptote project page](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/), to use it and install [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83035/154390) you can obtain good information to achieve it.

Comment: Oh wow! This looks really great. (+1 of course)